# Error al ejecutar el generador de códigos seleccionado

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Al tratar de crear un controlador

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me sale este error que no logro solucionar

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es la solución

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Asegúrate de que la solución compila correctamente antes de tratar de añadir el controlador

Comment: Si compila bien

Comment: Es medio raro el error, hace poco me paso algo parecido o a un compañero, no recuerdo bien. Pero tuvo o tuve que crear otro proyecto para crear los archivos

Comment: encontraste la solución al problema?

Comment: Nooo @IsamaraLópez